# Change the order of columns in geom_raster()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to order these columns so that the columns that is left most would have smallest sum of scaled_val and the right most column to have largest sum.

[image: Current plot]

Code to generate example dataset

```
n_pat <- 25
patient <- 1:n_pat
censoring <- ceil(rexp(n_pat, 1/30))
tumour_shrink <- (rbeta(n_pat, 2, 2) - 0.5) * 100

n_cytokines <- 15
cytokines <- paste("Cytokine", 1:n_cytokines)

response <- sample(c("PR", "NE", "CR", "PD", "SD"), size=n_pat,
                   replace = T)

missing_combination <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size=n_pat, replace=T)

changes <- matrix(runif(n_pat * n_cytokines, 1, 100), nrow=n_pat, ncol=n_cytokines)
changes[sample(1:dim(changes)[1], 4, replace = FALSE), sample(1:dim(changes)[2], 5, replace = F)] <- NA

df <- data.frame(patient, censoring, tumour_shrink, changes, missing_combination)
colnames(df) <- c("patient", "censoring", "tumour_shrink", cytokines, "missing_combination")
```

Code to generate current plot

```
normalize <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  up = x - min(x, na.rm=T)
  down = max(x, na.rm=T) - min(x, na.rm=T)
  return((2 * (up / down) - 1) * 100)
}

cdf <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cytokines) %>% 
  mutate(scaled_val = normalize(value)) %>% 
  mutate(important = ifelse((abs(scaled_val) > 85), TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(important = FALSE))
  
cdf %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(patient), y=name, fill=scaled_val)) +
  geom_raster(alpha=0.85) +
  geom_text(data=filter(cdf, important),
            aes(label="★"), colour="black", size=8, vjust=0.2, alpha=0.9) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", mid="white", high="red", guide="none") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste0("Pat ", patient)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0.3),
        plot.margin = unit(c(5, 5, 5, 5), "pt")) +
  coord_fixed()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder the variable `patient`, you could do that with `forcats`, here is an example:

```
cdf %>% 
  mutate(patient = fct_reorder(.f = as.factor(patient),
                               .x = scaled_val,
                               .fun = function(x)sum(x,na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=patient, y=name, fill=scaled_val)) 
  geom_raster(alpha=0.85) +
  geom_text(data=filter(cdf, important),
            aes(label="★"), colour="black", size=8, vjust=0.2, alpha=0.9) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", mid="white", high="red", guide="none") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste0("Pat ", patient)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0.3),
        plot.margin = unit(c(5, 5, 5, 5), "pt")) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]